# Determine if a point is inside a triangle formed by 3 points with given latitude/longitude

Tags: javascript, geometry, geolocation

I have 3 points ( lat , lon ) that form a triangle.How can i find if a point is inside this triangle?

Comment: Isn't this is a Project Euler problem?

Comment: How large is your triangle likely to be? Is it small enough to assume that the surface can be considered as flat or do you need spherical geometry?

Comment: Further to what Mark says, how do you define "inside" versus "outside"? If your points are Honolulu, Bangkok and Lagos so the triangle edge roughly follows the equator, is the North pole inside or is the South pole inside?

Comment: Firstly i have a starting point A.I compute a point B that is 500m far and with a bearing of 60 degrees.Point C is also 500m but with a bearing of 120 degrees.I want to know if a point is inside the region with an angle range of 60 degrees(from 60 to 120).B and C have the same lon.I dont know if i helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question is whether you can use a 2D approximation for this (in other words, is your triangle small enough).

If so, something simple like barycentric coordinates will work well.

Comment: The tricky bit is when it's a 2d space embedded on a 3d sphere, the edges of the triangles aren't lines, they're great arcs.  Technically you can still use barycentric coordinates, but the distance function is different, you have to deal with periodicity, and it's just a huge hassle.  The answers you want won't exactly match the 2d triangle answers for large or inconveniently placed triangles.

Answer (score 5):

Java Code for just triangle , that is 3 points.

```
    public static boolean pntInTriangle(double px, double py, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3) {

    double o1 = getOrientationResult(x1, y1, x2, y2, px, py);
    double o2 = getOrientationResult(x2, y2, x3, y3, px, py);
    double o3 = getOrientationResult(x3, y3, x1, y1, px, py);

    return (o1 == o2) && (o2 == o3);
}

private static int getOrientationResult(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double px, double py) {
    double orientation = ((x2 - x1) * (py - y1)) - ((px - x1) * (y2 - y1));
    if (orientation > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (orientation < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how this works.  Where did the magic expression in getOrientationResult come from?

Comment: The orientation formula is wrong. I found multiple sources that confirm that the formula for a triangle with points P1, P2 and P3 is: (p1.x - p3.x)*(p2.y - p3.y)-(p1.y - p3.y)*(p2.x - p3.x); and besides, the orientation of the three triangles have to be same as the orientation of the original triangle, which is not said here. Sources (sorry, they're in spanish, but the formulas are universal ;-) http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/mabellanas/tfcs/kirkpatrick/Aplicacion/algoritmos.htm#puntoInterior http://ouphenus.scienceontheweb.net/2008/07/13/un-punto-dentro-de-un-triangulo/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Javascript implementation of the barycentric coordinates solution [discussed here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html):

```
// Returns true if point P inside the triangle with vertices at A, B and C
// representing 2D vectors and points as [x,y]. Based on                        
// http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html
function pointInTriange(P, A, B, C) {
  // Compute vectors        
  function vec(from, to) {  return [to[0] - from[0], to[1] - from[1]];  }
  var v0 = vec(A, C);
  var v1 = vec(A, B);
  var v2 = vec(A, P);
  // Compute dot products
  function dot(u, v) {  return u[0] * v[0] + u[1] * v[1];  }
  var dot00 = dot(v0, v0);
  var dot01 = dot(v0, v1);
  var dot02 = dot(v0, v2);
  var dot11 = dot(v1, v1);
  var dot12 = dot(v1, v2);
  // Compute barycentric coordinates
  var invDenom = 1.0 / (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01);
  var u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * invDenom;
  var v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * invDenom;
  // Check if point is in triangle
  return (u >= 0) && (v >= 0) && (u + v < 1);
}
```

It's said to be faster than the cross-product based solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Most languages include a function for this. In Java it's Polygon.contains()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html

Simply create a polygon from your points, and then call contains() on your test point.

Comment: It's not really the language but the framework provided with the language in this case. It is always good to know what the software does. For something as simple as finding whether a point lies within a triangle, I don't think using Polygon would be the best / most efficient solution.

Comment: I agree with @Christo. you do not always have `awt` at your disposal.

Comment: this is not ideal as Polygon.contains() supports any kind of polygon, and therefore, the algorithm is much more complex and heavy that other manual (but straightforward) solutions provided here on other answers. Besides, awt is not a set of classes Java developers usually are crazy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use point-polygon test.

It's simple. Draw a line from your point to East for a big enough distance. Count the number of times that line intersects with your plygon. If it's even, your point is outside, if odd, its inside.

That works for any type of polygon.

Comment: If you use this method, make sure to handle the edge cases - two parallel lines can have infinitely many intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ray casting algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

It is pretty simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SameSide(p1,p2, a,b)
    cp1 = CrossProduct(b-a, p1-a)
    cp2 = CrossProduct(b-a, p2-a)
    if DotProduct(cp1, cp2) >= 0 then return true
    else return false

function PointInTriangle(p, a,b,c)
    if SameSide(p,a, b,c) and SameSide(p,b, a,c)
        and SameSide(p,c, a,b) then return true
    else return false
```

Explained at the link below

http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html

Comment: too much "magic" going on in this example. `CrossProduct` is never expained.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this today! Also with (lat, lon), actually (theta, phi), although I knew a little more about the mesh I was working with. I'm working with (theta, phi) with 0 <= theta <= PI && 0 <= phi <= 2*PI.

You'll find that you might have some trouble if one of the vertices is at the top or bottom of your sphere, since in my case phi isn't really defined. You end up with a singularity there. You've basically got a square, which makes it easier to check whether your point lies within it or not.

In all other cases, if you've converted your point into  (lat, lon) / (theta, phi). It should be simple to just use the method as described by @Michelle Six.